# FTP task SSIS for moving files from linux ftp to windows share?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

Can we use FTP task for sending files from linux ftp to windows share?If so can anyone help me with the syntax as i will be using the operation as receive files.

Answer (score 0):

why not try the SSIS on Linux : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2017/05/17/ssis-helsinki-is-available-in-sql-server-vnext-ctp2-1/

use mount to access windows file share and run the package in Linux.